# parsing XML and GPS data to list

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, gps, linq-to-xml

```
<lap1>
     <Track>
  <Trackpoint>
     <Time>2012-03-29T08:06:57Z</Time>
     <Position>
       <LatitudeDegrees>46.2950333</LatitudeDegrees>
      <LongitudeDegrees>7.1046736</LongitudeDegrees>
    </Position>
     <AltitudeMeters>1782.4216309</AltitudeMeters>
<DistanceMeters>0.0000000</DistanceMeters>
<HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
  <Value>112</Value>
</HeartRateBpm>
<SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
   </Trackpoint>
   <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2012-03-29T08:06:58Z</Time>
    <Position>
      <LatitudeDegrees>46.2950271</LatitudeDegrees>
      <LongitudeDegrees>7.1046776</LongitudeDegrees>
     </Position>
    <AltitudeMeters>1782.4216309</AltitudeMeters>
     <DistanceMeters>0.1714377</DistanceMeters>
<HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
  <Value>112</Value>
</HeartRateBpm>
<SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
  </Trackpoint>
  </Track>
</lap1>
```

i have this piece of xml from my gps device and im trying to parse it into a list track

```
public class track
{
    public float positionx;
    public float positiony;
    public float altitude;
    public DateTime Time;
}
```

having not done much xml work i have been reading various xml methods including XPath and LinqToXML but im struggling to parse the xml, particularly 'Position and its sub values

i would be very grateful for any assistance on this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml"); 

var tracks = (from elem in doc.Root.Descendants("Trackpoint") 
               select new track() 
               { 
                   Time = DateTime.Parse(elem.Element("Time").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),  
                   positionx = float.Parse(elem.Element("Positition").Element("LatitudeDegrees").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),  
                   positiony = float.Parse(elem.Element("Positition").Element("LongitudeDegrees").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),  
                   altitude = float.Parse(elem.Element("AltitudeMeters").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),  
               });
```

Tell me if it works!

Comment: Should be "Trackpoint" cause Descendants extension method is case-sensitive.